# Validating URL arguments in TeamCity build step curl command

Tags: curl, command-line, continuous-integration, teamcity

In one of TeamCity build steps we sending GET request to some webapp that we have with relevant argument that provide some information for us.

In the screenshot, for example, we sending `teamcity.build.id` (variable that TeamCity generates) and another variable which represent environment variable defined in TeamCity parameters.

The query arguments that passed, can *accidentally* receive values that will break the whole build process. For example, **Spaces** (if envVar will receive value with spaces).

What is the best practice to somehow sanitize this request? remove spaces/other problematic values in arguments?

[image]

**P.S.** it's not possible to do those validations on the webapp side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [Typed Parameters](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Typed+Parameters). You can specify a regex that is used to validate the build parameter before the build runs.

Here's a blog post with more details and examples of using typed parameters. https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/05/typed-parameters-and-continuous-deployment/

Comment: Thanks. It seems like the exact approach that I need. But, it acts the regex validation seems to act very strange :/ I just need to validate that no empty spaces exist, and it prompts the validation message just in any possible case (and I validate my regex pattern before)